# Should the questions posted on Stack Overflow have "Hello .." & "Thanks" statements?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Should the questions posted on Stack Overflow have "Hello Everyone" & "Thanks" statements in the beginning and end?

The reason for this doubt is that once I posted like this and someone edited and removed these. But, sometimes, I find some users posting like this and it doesn't get edited (even one of my recent posts didn't get edited). So, it's slightly confusing as to what is the SO etiquette for this?

If there is already a question for this in Meta, please point to me that and I will be happy to close this question (I was unable to find it though).